# How can I find the sum of multiple groups within a series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a short series of ~60 values. What I need to do is find the largest sum of 24 consecutive values in the series.

e.g. I would need to be able to find the sums of the groups [0:23],[1:24],[2:25],[3:26], ... , [37:60] and determine which group has the largest sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rolling method on a serie :
`serie.rolling(24).sum()`

To get directly the max 
`max_idx = serie.rolling(24).sum().idxmax()`

You range of interest is `[max_idx-24+1:max_idx]` (from index `max_idx - 24 + 1` to index `max_idx` (both included) , so be careful if you want to retrieve these elements, with `.loc` should be fine but if going back to the original list or if using `iloc` then you'll have to go to `max_idx + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Series` is small, you can use a simple `dict` comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from operator import itemgetter

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=60))

result = {f'{i} - {i + 24}': s[i:i + 24].sum() for i in range(len(s) - 24)}

max(result.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Output:

```
'6 - 30'
```